# numpy.str_ error pre-processing texts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I am trying to pre-process some texts in a column in pandas dataframe using the following code. The pre-processing includes lowercase, tokenize and remove stopwords. However, I get the following `numpy.str_ object is not callable` error. Any idea how I could solve this? Thanks.

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import re
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

i = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
j = list(string.punctuation) 

stopwords = set(i).union(j)

def preprocess(x):
    x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x().lower())                  # get rid of noise
    x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(stopwords) if len(w) > 3]  # remove stopwords
    return ' '.join(x)   

preprocess2 = np.vectorize(preprocess)
```

```
merged_sort['processed_text'] = merged_sort['translated_text'].apply(preprocess2)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e3eee761f15b> in <module>
----> 1 merged_sort['processed_text'] = merged_sort['translated_text'].apply(preprocess2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2089             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2090 
-> 2091         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2092 
   2093     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2159             res = func()
   2160         else:
-> 2161             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2162 
   2163             # Convert args to object arrays first

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2119 
   2120             inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2121             outputs = func(*inputs)
   2122 
   2123             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

<ipython-input-21-1631cf3dded9> in preprocess(x)
     12 
     13 def preprocess(x):
---> 14     x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x().lower())                  # get rid of noise
     15     x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(stopwords) if len(w) > 3]  # remove stopwords
     16     return ' '.join(x)

TypeError: 'numpy.str_' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have `x().lower()` in there; did you mean `x.lower()` instead?

Comment: Thanks. If I remove that I get this error ```AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'lower'```

Comment: Yes, so `x` happens to be a floating point number but you're trying to "lower" it, which results in an error. Do you have any numbers in the column? In any case, you can try `str(x).lower()` there.